# Разработка лексического анализатора

Tags: c++

Имеется входной язык, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Программа>::=<Объявление переменных><Описание вычислений>
<Описание вычислений>::=Begin <Список присваиваний> End
<Объявление переменных>::=Var <Список переменных>
<Список переменных>::=<Идент>|<Идент>,<Список переменных>|
 <Идент> ; <Список переменных>
<Список присваиваний>::=<Присваивание>|
 <Присваивание><Список присваиваний>
<Присваивание> ::=<Идент> := <Выражение> ;
<Выражение> ::= <Ун.оп.><Подвыражение> | <Подвыражение>
<Подвыражение> :: = ( <Выражение> ) | <Операнд> |
 <Подвыражение> <Бин.оп.> <Подвыражение>
<Ун.оп.> ::="-"
<Бин.оп> ::="-" | "+" | "*" | "/"
<Операнд> ::= <Идент>|<Константа>
<Идент> ::= <Буква> <Идент> | <Буква>
<Константа> ::= <Цифра> <Константа> | <Цифра>
```

По заданию необходимо:

1. Определить, какие классы лексем будут в языке.
2. Составить контрольные примеры на реализуемом языке. Хотя бы один пример должен проверять поведение  программы при наличии недопустимых символов в транслируемом файле.
3. Запрограммировать и отладить модуль сканирования. Выполнить тестирование на контрольных примерах. Результатом работы должна быть таблица, содержащая лексемы и признаки их классов. Необходимо включить в результирующий файл информацию о номерах строк исходного текста транслируемой программы.

И вот здесь начинается совсем не понимание всего и вся. Вроде понятно с первым пунктом, но как это реализовать, например, в C++ не ясно, потому что по входному языку ничего не ясно и чуждый лес. Буду очень благодарен, если найдутся примеры или хорошая теория, и поясните что к чему.

Comment: видимо вам нужны `lex` и `yacc` если я правильно понял задание

Comment: Это преподаватель указал при написании курсовой работы. А сейчас сказал можно использовать любой язык и любую программу. А теоретического материала выданного им по сути - нет. Так что даже нет представления с чего начинать и как это делать, ну и примеров какого-либо кода для разбора также не нашел, который бы направил в нужное русло

Comment: а что с самим языком? псевдокод, описанный выше, полностью описывает этот язык или нет? Если да, то первая задача считайте решена, так как в псевдокоде описываются эти самые классы. Правда не совсем понятно с некоторыми классами (вроде "программа" и "описание вычеслений"), но это уже уточняйте у препода

Comment: ну вот что за вузы - не дают никакой теоретической базы:) или может проблема в чем то другом?

Comment: «Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты» Ахо aka «Книга с драконом» в зубы... думаю ни кто не будет спорить, что лучше теории нет...

Comment: [Альфред Ахо и компания. Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компиляторы:_принципы,_технологии_и_инструменты)

Comment: видимо вам нужны `lex` и `yacc` если я правильно понял задание